# C++ type of argument to ifstream::open()

Tags: c++, ifstream

What type must I make my file name to use it as an argument to `ifstream.open()`?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    string x,y,file;

    string file = argv[1];
    ifstream in;
    in.open(file);
    in >> x;
    in >> y;
    ...
```

With this code, I get the following error:

```
main.cpp|20|error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char,
     std::char_traits<char> >::open(std::string&)'|
gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\include\c++\fstream|525|note: candidates are: void std::basic_ifstream<_CharT,
     _Traits>::open(const char*, std::_Ios_Openmode) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]|
```

UPDATE:

i get this error
[image]

Comment: now you updated the question with a completely different problem. try running the program with the debugger and see where it crashes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The constructor takes a const char* (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/ifstream/) so you should do it like this:

```
in.open(argv[1]);
```

or if you really want to use the file string variable, then

```
in.open(file.c_str());
```

Comment: Also, if you use a slightly newer compiler, it will have an overload for std::string as well. Required by C++0x.

Comment: @Bo: wow, wait, what? C++ is finally going to support its `string` class?

Comment: @rubenvb: Yeah, that's the advantage of a revised standard! :-) Historically, the stream classes were designed long before there was a string class, so they couldn't support one. And nobody thought of going back and fix that. Until now!

Comment: weird i tried using the `in.open(argv[1]);`, it compiles but it crashes the console.

Comment: Or, if you have an older compiler and boost ... `boost::filesystem::ifstream in; in.open(file);`

Comment: @Maris Bancila, @Rob Adams, @Bo Persson, @Hans Passant .. well i updated first post, the program compiles now, but the command window crashes