# sourceFile.open(filepath);

Tags: c++, io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ type of argument to ifstream::open()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251814/c-type-of-argument-to-ifstreamopen)
>   [C++ ifstream error using string as opening file path.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323619/c-ifstream-error-using-string-as-opening-file-path)

Whats wrong with

```
ifstream sourceFile;
sourceFile.open(filepath);
```

I am getting something about:

> no matching function call to `ifstream::open(string&)`

Whats wrong?

Same with

```
ifstream sourceFile(filepath)
```

Where filepath is a string

Answer (score 2):

As of C++11, iostreams can take a `string` as the parameter to name the file to be opened -- but this was added in C++ 11, so quite a few libraries don't include it yet. Updating to the latest version of your compiler/library *might* help (but then again, it might not -- I doubt that support is quite universal even yet).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `filepath` is a `string`.
`Open` only takes raw pointers.
So do this - `Open(filepath.c_str());`

Answer (score 0):

It takes a `char* filename` and not a **string** as argument.

```
sourceFile.open(filepath.c_str());
```

---

```
The Function is std::ifstream::open
    void open ( const char * filename, ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in );
```

(**[Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/)**)